# Generator inertia

Tags: power, generator, power-grid

I am little bit confused with the idea of generator inertia for interconnected system. Below you can find my small questions.

- What is the meaning of 200 GVAs as a metric of inertia?
- If there is no primary response (no inertia) would any generation tripping lead to an unstopped frequency drop? Or there will be nadir frequency point?

Answer (score 3):

I never heard of this before but I found that there's a pretty good explanation on [Inertia](http://watt-logic.com/2017/10/12/inertia/) over at Watt Logic.

[image]

> The frequency fluctuations are resisted by the sources of inertia on the grid – the principle of conservation of energy requires that power in must equal power out at all times, so when there is a power imbalance on the system, energy is transferred between the kinetic energy stored in the rotating turbines and the power system in order to maintain equilibrium between generation and demand.

> System inertia is expressed in GVAs (GVA seconds), which are equivalent to GJ. (Electrical power in watts is defined as the product of voltage and current (P = VI) per unit of time, and therefore the power rating of electrical equipment is often quoted in “MVA” which stands for Mega Volt Amps.)

> The amount of the store of kinetic energy that can be used for managing frequency is restricted by the frequency limits being applied. **For example, for a frequency deviation of ±0.5 Hz, only ±2% of the stored kinetic energy can be transferred before the frequency limit is exceeded. For a system with 200 GVA.s, this equates to 4 GVA.s (4 GJ) or approximately 4 seconds for an imbalance of 1 GW.** [Emphasis mine.]

> In order for a machine to contribute to system inertia, there has to be a direct electromagnetic coupling between the machine and the power system which allows disturbances on the system to be translated into a mechanical torque that acts on the machine rotor.

I think the answer to your second question is that if the generation can't correct for the frequency drop then it has to start shedding load to prevent a system shutdown.